# Adding a JS Button Click Handler function with chaining javascript functions within it for a Book Finder program

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling

I basically have a help function file **(helper.js)** that is used to test my functions that are implemented in **script.js**. After the project is rendered the user should be able to search for a book that is provided in a list of books **(bookList.js)** and when found the book is found it is displayed in in this HTML **(index.html)** file loaded to the browser. The issue I am having is implementing a searchBtnClickHandler function in the script.js file. I know there can be anonymous click handlers but how do I have a defined click handler function **(defined as searchBtnClickHandler in script.js)** connected to the search button and chain the previous functions *(captureSearchValue, filterBooks and structureBooksAsHtml)* in it?
I hope the instructions in the comments provided with each task provides more reference of what each part of the program is intended to do. If not please comment so I can edit it to add more clarification here. Thank you!

**script.js**

```
// Click handler for search button
const captureSearchValue = () => {
  const input = document.getElementById("search-bar").value;
  return input;
};

// Filter books based on search input and render filtered books to the DOM
const filterBooks = (input, books) => {
  const filteredBooks = [];
  let flattenedBooks = flattenObjectValuesIntoArray(books); // Call existing function
  for (let book = 0; book < books.length; book++) {
    // Search in the flattened books array, also make lowercase to include case insensitive results
    if (
      flattenedBooks[book]
        .map((e) => e.toLowerCase())
        .includes(input.toLowerCase())
    ) {
      filteredBooks.push(books[book]);
    }
  }
  return filteredBooks;

  // const filteredBooks = books.filter(book => book.tags.includes(input));
  // const filteredBooks = books.filter(book => book.tags.includes(input));
  // books.filter((book) => book.tags.includes(input));
};

// Empty the book list container, iterate over list of filtered books, return list of books formatted as HTML using the function in `helper.js`
const structureBooksAsHtml = (filteredBooks) => {
  const bookHTML = [];
  for (let book = 0; book < filteredBooks.length; book++) {
    bookHTML.push(structureBookAsHtml(filteredBooks[book]));
  }
  return bookHTML;
};

// Handler triggered when a user clickers the "Search" button. Chains previously defined functions together to filter books based on the search value, formats the books as HTML and renders them to the DOM
const searchBtnClickHandler = (event) => {
  captureSearchValue();
  filterBooks();
  structureBooksAsHtml();
};

// Grab search button from the DOM
searchBtn = document.getElementById("search-btn");
// Attach an event listener to the search button
searchBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  searchBtnClickHandler(books);
});
```

**helper.js**

```
/ Flatten object keys into an array so that we search the entire object by the input value
const flattenObjectValuesIntoArray = (arrOfObjs) => {
  let flattenedObj;
  const flattenedObjsArr = [];
  for (let obj = 0; obj < arrOfObjs.length; obj++) {
    const objValues = Object.values(arrOfObjs[obj]);
    flattenedObj = [...objValues.flat()]
    flattenedObjsArr.push(flattenedObj)
  }
  return flattenedObjsArr;
};

// Structure filtered books as HTML and return
const structureBookAsHtml = (book) => {
  const bookDiv = document.createElement("div");
  bookDiv.setAttribute('class', 'bookDiv');
  
  const bookTitle = document.createElement("h2");
  bookTitle.innerHTML = book.title;
  bookTitle.setAttribute('class', 'bookTitle');

  const bookAuthor = document.createElement("h3");
  bookAuthor.innerHTML = book.author;

  const bookTags = document.createElement("p");
  bookTags.innerHTML = book.tags.join(", ");

  bookDiv.append(bookTitle, bookAuthor, bookTags);
  
  return bookDiv;
};

const renderBooksToDom = (elements) => {
  const bookListContainer = document.querySelector("#bookList");
  bookListContainer.innerHTML = "";

  bookListContainer.append(...elements);
};
```

**bookList.js**

```
const books = [
  {
    title: "The City We Became",
    author: "N. K. Jemisin",
    tags: ["fantasy", "fiction", "afrofutursim", "science fiction", "sci-fi"]
  },
  {
    title: "The Catcher in the Rye",
    author: "J. D. Salinger",
    tags: ["fiction", "young adult", "YA", "realism", "coming of age", "classic"]
  },
  {
    title: "The Hundred Thousand Kingdoms",
    author: "N. K. Jemisin",
    tags: ["fantasy", "fiction", "adventure", "series"]
  },
  {
    title: "Sapiens: A Brief History of Humankind",
    author: "Yuval Noah Harari",
    tags: ["nonfiction", "history", "anthropology", "science", "sociology"]
  },
  {
    title: "Behave: The Biology of Humans at Our Best and Worst",
    author: "Robert M. Sapolsky",
    tags: ["nonfiction", "anthropology", "science", "sociology", "biology"]
  },
  {
    title: "The Parable of the Talents",
    author: "Octavia Butler", 
    tags: ["fiction", "dystopian", "science fiction"]
  },
  {
    title: "1984",
    author: "George Orwell", 
    tags: ["fiction", "dystopian", "science fiction", "classics", "adult"]
  },
  {
    title: "Remarkably Bright Creatures",
    author: "Shelby Van Pelt",
    tags: ["fiction", "mystery", "magical realism"]
  },
  {
    title: "Crying in H Mart",
    author: "Michelle Zauner",
    tags: ["memoir", "nonfiction", "autobiography"]
  },
  {
    title: "Wild: From Lost to Found on the Pacific Crest Trail",
    author: "Cheryl Strayed",
    tags: ["nonfiction", "memoir", "adventure", "travel"]
  }
]
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="bookList.js"></script>
    <script src="bookList.test.js"></script>
    <script src="helper.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Book Finder</h1>
    <input id="search-bar" type="text" placeholder="Search for books by tags">
    <button class="btn" id="search-btn">Search</button>
    <div id="bookList">
      <!-- List of books will be rendered here -->
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
const searchBtnClickHandler = (event) => {
  captureSearchValue();
  filterBooks();
  structureBooksAsHtml();
};
```

In this line of the code I am trying to chain the functions to the event. I think this is where I am falling short at but I am open to any suggestions on if the error lies in this part of code or somewhere else.

Comment: `event.captureSearchValue();` doesn't make sense. `captureSearchValue()` is an ordinary function, not a method of `books`. Also, calling the function parameter `event` seems wrong, since you're passing the `books` array, not an event.

Comment: @Barmar Hi thank you for pointing that out I just removed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions like `captureSearchValue()` are ordinary functions, not methods of the `books` array. You should call them with arguments, not as `event.functionName()`. Then capture the return value in another variable so you can pass it to the next function in the chain.

```
// Handler triggered when a user clickers the "Search" button. Chains previously defined functions together to filter books based on the search value, formats the books as HTML and renders them to the DOM
const searchBtnClickHandler = (books) => {
  let input = captureSearchValue();
  let filtered = filterBooks(input, books);
  let array_of_divs = structureBooksAsHtml(filtered);
  renderBooksToDom(array_of_divs);
};
```

Comment: That makes sense, thank you for sharing that. I'm not sure why but when I used that for searchBtnClickHandler, it returns this error: Given a search for `'fiction'`, expected the `bookTitle` `div` to have `6` child elements.

Comment: I haven't checked the rest of your logic, you might have other problems.

Comment: `book < books.length` should be `book < flattenedBooks.length`, You could also use `flattenedBooks.filter()`.

Comment: Could it also be the structureBooksAsHtml function may need to be written a different way? Their instructions was worded different than the comments but the function is supposed to do the following:     The structureBooksAsHtml() function takes a list of books as a parameter, iterates over the list, formats them as HTML using the structureBookAsHtml() helper function, and returns an array of formatted book elements.

Comment: My above comment was wrong. Both arrays have the same length, so it doesn't matter which length you use.

Comment: Oh okay thank you for clarifying that because when I ran it with that change it had the same result. I wasn't sure if that was expected or not.

Comment: I had a typo `array_of_object` instead of `array_of_objects`.

Comment: Is "Given a search for 'fiction', expected the bookTitle div to have 6 child elements." really the error you're getting? I don't see anything like that in your code.

Comment: Yes I'm running the code on a testing platform that runs test cases against my code and for the test for searchBtnClickHandler() it returns that error to me.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that was what you meant after I posted the question. Anyway, do you still have the problem after correcting the typo?

Comment: Yeah I was thinking that there was something wrong with how the searchBtnClickHandler function but your changes made sense so that's why I was thinking that maybe it was an issue somewhere else in the code.

Comment: Found the problem. I was calling `structureBooksAsHtml()` twice. I didn't need to call it in the last line.

Comment: @Badmar It works now, good catch! Thank you so much for your help, I really do appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have to make sure that the search still works even when the user presses space after typing in the genre.
Here is how my filterBooks() function looks like.

```
    const filterBooks = (searchValue, books) => {
      const sanitizedSearchValue = searchValue.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, ''); // Remove spaces from search input and convert to lowercase
  const searchGenres = sanitizedSearchValue.split(','); // Split search input into individual genres
  return books.filter((book) => {
    const sanitizedTitle = book.title.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, ''); // Remove spaces from book title and convert to lowercase
    const sanitizedAuthor = book.author.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, ''); // Remove spaces from book author and convert to lowercase
    const sanitizedTags = book.tags.map(tag => tag.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '')); // Remove spaces from tags and convert to lowercase
    const titleMatch = searchGenres.some(genre => sanitizedTitle.includes(genre));
    const authorMatch = searchGenres.some(genre => sanitizedAuthor.includes(genre));
    const tagsMatch = searchGenres.some(genre => sanitizedTags.includes(genre));
    return titleMatch || authorMatch || tagsMatch;
  });
};
```